# How run a Python script from another script and get resulting global dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say you have a string containing a path to a Python script and you want to load and execute that script in transparent way (so that there are not fundamental differences for inner script compared to being run directly via “python path”). And then get the resulting global dict. I thought that runpy.run_path() does this but there are two issues. If the path contains some unicode character then it doesn't work (see http://bugs.python.org/issue17588). And most importantly, given global dict is just a copy of original one, since this original one is purged when temporary module object is garbage collected. So a function object have corrupted __globals__ dict (see http://bugs.python.org/issue18331).

Have you any ideas how to run the inner script?

*Update:* See my current approach – http://bpaste.net/show/RzAbQxLNXiJsXYm2fplz/ . Any suggestions? Improvements? For example about the details of what can be different from point of view of a script being run. I know about issue with realoading __main__.

Comment: rewrite the "inner" script to be usable as a module...

Comment: [execfile()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile).

Comment: @l4mpi: The path and inner script is not fixed.

Comment: `random = __import__("random")` to import the `random` module using a string.

Comment: @TankorSmash: I don't want to import it by name, but run it from path. Also the path can contain unicode characters, so I cannot even use compile() function.

Comment: You could add the module's path to the `sys.path` list

Comment: @user87690 why would the path containing unicode prevent you from using `compile`? Compile takes a string (or AST object) as input, so you can just open and read the file and pass the contents to compile.

Comment: @martineau: execfile() does not exist in Python 3. I could rewrite it using exec() but for nice traceback, I need to get code object first using compile which doesn't work with Unicode filename.

Comment: @l4mpi: Just try it, it doesn't work (on Windows). Some inner C code tries to encode the filename (even if there's no reason to do so, it's a string). See http://bugs.python.org/issue17588, http://bugs.python.org/issue11619.

Comment: Surely you can temporarily work around the unicode filename bug in `Complile()`...

Comment: @user87690 these issues just mean you can't pass unicode paths as the second argument to `compile`; just try passing something else. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#compile): `The filename argument should give the file from which the code was read; pass some recognizable value if it wasn’t read from a file ('<string>' is commonly used).` If this doesn't work for you, consider copying the required files to a temporary folder and executing them from there.

Comment: @martineau: I'm trying to. What's funny is that whole this problem is a workaround to another bug which I encountered when trying to workaround another bug. :-)

Comment: @l4mpi: I cannot copy the files – they souldn't notice that they're being run from another script and not directly. When you put '<string>' to compile, then the tracebacks of inner script doesn't show code lines. My current approach is to compile with '<script>' and then recreate the code object using original filename.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a module executes the code at the top level, and that module's "global" namespace gets imported as the name of the module

```
james@bodacious:~$cat test.py
def func():
  pass

myname = "michael caine"

print "hello, %s" % myname
james@bodacious:~$python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 12 2013, 18:42:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
hello, michael caine
>>> dir(test)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'func', 'myname']
>>>
```

if the code you want to be run is at the top level of the file, just importing the module will execute the code *and* give you access to its "global" namespace all in one convenient package. If the code you want to run isn't at the top level (eg, if it's in a `main()` function that only gets triggered with the common `if __name__=="__main__"` trick), you can call that function yourself:

```
james@bodacious:~$cat test.py

def main():
    print "hello there!"

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
james@bodacious:~$python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 12 2013, 18:42:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.main()
hello there!
>>>
```

Of course, it's possible that you file you want to import is not in sys.path, so can't be simply loaded with `import`. A simplistic solution might be to manipulate `sys.path`, but [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) describes better solutions using `imp.load_source()`

Comment: This will only work if the script's top level logic is in a function that gets called from the `if __name__ == "__main__"` boilerplate. While that's a good design, you may not be able to rely on it being used by other code.

Comment: That's correct, calling `main()` will only be useful if the code you want to run is inside a function called `main()`. If it's inside a different function, you'll have to call that function instead. If the function takes arguments, you'll have to provide those as well.

Comment: I have the path of the script, it may not be in sys.path to be loaded. Also this doesn't work for unicode filename, since there's a bug so you cannot “import α”.